# Coloring Formattable Data Table in R - Stock Data

Tags: r, datatable, formattable

I have a datatable storing the daily/weekly/monthly returns for several stocks that I am trying to color with R's formattable package. I want negative returns to be red, and positive returns to be green. Or to get fancy, have a separate gradient for positive and negative values - so if Apple was down 10% for a day it would be dark red, and if Amazon was down 2%, that cell would be a lighter red - and vice versa for positive returns (light and dark green).

My issue is that when I use a red-green gradient, the colors in the middle appear brown-ish colored. The code I have below has transparent/white as the low end of the gradient, and green as the upper end, but is pretty tough to differentiate.

My datatable looks something like:

```
Stock day  week   month
AAPL   1.5  3.2   10.6
AMZN   3.2  5.3   4.4
BA    -2.1 -4.0  -10.5
PYPL   -5  -8.5  -12.1



Green <- "#71ca99"

sign_formatter <- formatter("span", 
                            style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x > 0, "green", 
                                                             ifelse(x < 0, "red", "black"))))
sign_formatter(c(-1, 0, 1))

returns <- formattable(stocks_df, align =c("l","c","c","c","c"), list(
  `Stock` = formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = "grey",font.weight = "bold")), 
  daily_return = color_tile("transparent", Green),
  week_return = color_tile("transparent", Green),
  month_return = color_tile("transparent", Green)))
```

@dc37

I am using the exact code you suggested - the colors are working perfectly. But when I sort by weekly return like in the example below, to get stocks with the best performance for the week, it is not sorting highest to lowest (having the same issue when I try to sort by worst performing stocks).

Here is a picture of what my formattable output looks like. I am also running this in Shiny, not sure if that is what could be throwing the error with sorting.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution will be to create multiple `ifelse` statement in order to set 5 different colors (red / lightred / white / lightgreen / green) in function of the value of each columns.

Here, a possible way of doing it:

```r
Test <- formatter("span",
                  style = x ~ style(display = "block", font.weight = "bold",color = "black","border-radius" = "4px",
                                 "padding-right" = "4px",
                                 "background-color" = ifelse(x <= -10, "red", ifelse(x > -10 & x <= -2, "tomato", ifelse(x > -2 & x <= 2, "white", ifelse(x > 2 & x <= 10, "palegreen",ifelse(x > 10, "green",NA)))))),
                  x ~ percent(x/100))

formattable(stocks_df,align =c("l","c","c","c","c"), list(
  `Stock` = formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = "grey",font.weight = "bold")),
  day = Test,
  week = Test, 
  month = Test))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

**Reproducible example**

```r
structure(list(Stock = c("AAPL", "AMZN", "BA", "PYPL"), day = c(1.5, 
3.2, -2.1, -5), week = c(3.2, 5.3, -4, -8.5), month = c(10.6, 
4.4, -10.5, -12.1)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55b7eeb735c0>)
```

Comment: when I sort the data table, it is not sorting correctly (highest return to lowest return, and vice versa). Any idea why this could be?

Comment: What do you mean by `sorting` the table ? can you edit your question and add the code you are using to sort the table and the image of what it looks like in `formattable` ?

Comment: When I sorted the dataframe into my r session by doing `formattable(stocks_df[order(week),] ....` it gives me the right sorting. Try only the formattable command without shiny. If the output is correct, it means that it is related to Shiny and how the reading of the dataframe is made.

Comment: I just ran it outside a shiny environment and it sorted fine. so looks like Shiny is causing the issue somehow

Comment: At least, you know where to dig into. Sorry, I'm not familiar with Shiny, can't help with that.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful anwer. May I ask, how sould we modify `formatter` in order to set gradient colors row-wisely instead of `"background-color" = ifesle (...)`?