# How to create table that colors in observations based upon their percentage values?

Tags: r, dataframe

I created a table that shows the count and percentage of observations for each 'Grade`, breaking down subdividing by whether or not each observation a yes or a no in the 'Essay' column. To do this, I used the tabyl package:

```
library(janitor)
firsttable <- tabyl(df, Essay, Grade) %>%
  adorn_percentages("col") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 1) %>%
  adorn_ns()
firsttable
```

To generate the below table:

[image]

As you can see, I have added both the count and percentage of each column for every value.

My end goal is to create a data table using `formattable` which colors in each value by it's percentage. To do that, I followed these instructions: [Coloring Formattable Data Table in R - Stock Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60498912/coloring-formattable-data-table-in-r-stock-data)

```
Test <- formatter("span", style = x ~ style(display = "block", font.weight = "bold",color = "black","border-radius" = "4px",
                                            "padding-right" = "4px",
                                            "background-color" = ifelse(x <= 20, "red", ifelse(x > 20 & x <= 40, "tomato", ifelse(x > 40 & x <= 60, "white", ifelse(x > 2 & x <= 80, "palegreen",ifelse(x > 80, "green",NA)))))),
                  x ~ percent(x/100))

d <- formattable(firsttable,align =c("l","c","c","c"), list(
  `Essat` = formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = "grey",font.weight = "bold")),
  A = Test,
  B = Test, 
  C = Test,
  D = Test))
```

This should make my table represent the table below, wherein the color is determined by the percentage of that given value (with higher percentages being darker green and lower percentages being darker red). I also want my table to include the count in parentheses, as in `firsttable`. Unfortunately, my variables are factors since I am including both the count and percentage. This prevents me from using the `ifelse` statement in order to group the colors by percentage level.

[image]

I am trying to work around this, but am really stuck.

```
structure(list(Grade = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), Essay = c("Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", 
"Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"Y", "N", "N", "N")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-44L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you can transpose the table if you like.

```
library(formattable)
df = structure(list(Grade = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                         "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
                         "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                         "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), Essay = c("Y", 
                                                                                      "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                                                                                      "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", 
                                                                                      "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
                                                                                      "Y", "N", "N", "N")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                -44L))

df2 = df %>% 
  mutate(NY = ifelse(Essay == "Y", 1, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(Grade) %>% 
  summarise(
    Y = mean(NY) * 100,
    N = (1 - mean(NY)) * 100,
  )

Test <- formatter("span", style = x ~ style(display = "block", font.weight = "bold",color = "black","border-radius" = "4px",
                                            "padding-right" = "4px",
                                            "background-color" = ifelse(x <= 20, "red", ifelse(x > 20 & x <= 40, "tomato", ifelse(x > 40 & x <= 60, "white", ifelse(x > 2 & x <= 80, "palegreen",ifelse(x > 80, "green",NA)))))),
                  x ~ percent(x/100))

d <- formattable(df2,align =c("l","c","c","c"), list(
  `Essat` = formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = "grey",font.weight = "bold")),
  Y = Test,
  N = Test))

d
```